# Editing list containers

Tags: python, list

Presently I have build a program that counts certain critera in a list which stores the data in a dictionary then at the end I add it to a new list.

```
count_occurances = Counter(lister_agent).values()
my_list.append(list(count_occurances))
```

I may get something like the list below with two containers in it:

```
my_list = [[123,1,3],[258,9,7]]
```

The problem I then have is editing the containers in the list based off different parameters. For example editing container [0]:

```
for y in my_list[0]:
    if y > 100:
        my_list.remove(y)
```

Doing this I get the error:

```
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `my_list` contains `[123,1,3]`.  It does not contain `123` as a separate element.

Comment: `my_list.remove` -> `my_list[0].remove`

Comment: In your case it should be `my_list[0].remove(y)` because you're looping over `my_list[0]` and you're trying to remove an integer from a list that contains lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your for loop is going through `my_list[0]` which is `[123,1,3]`.
meaning y will be 123 then 1 then 3.
You are trying to do `mylist.remove(123)`.
since 123 is not in `my_list ([[123,1,3],[258,9,7]])` it doesn't get removed.
123 only exists in `my_list[0]`

Comment: what you could do is my_list[0].remove(y)

Answer (score 0):

**You have nested list so you should use nested for loop too.**

```
my_list = [[123, 1, 3], [258, 9, 7]]

for lst in my_list:
    for i in lst:
        if i > 100:
            lst.remove(i)

print(my_list)
```

**output:**

```
[[1, 3], [9, 7]]
```